# GCC Linking to C++ Library Query

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a situation where I need to compile C code and C++ code aswell as linking to a C++ static libary.

This works by  using the following command:

```
gcc  file.cpp file.c -xc++ -pthread -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc -L/path -l:liba.a -lm -o program
```

However, if I change the order of link commands (switching `-lm` and `-l:libary.a`) as follows:

```
gcc  file.cpp file.c -xc++ -pthread -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc -lm -L/path -l:liba.a -o program
```

This does not work as the compiler complains:

```
liba.o: undefined reference to symbol 'log@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Use `g++` instead of `gcc` for compiling c++.

Comment: linking happens from left to right, you need to move `-lm` *after* `-l:liba.a` because `liba.a` declares a need for something from `libm` (namely log)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)